# UIBarButtonItem Title Selection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I am using a `UIBarButtonItem` as a title in my toolbar.  I have set the style to plain and am setting the `title` property.  Everything is working well except that when a user clicks the title is still acts like a button and highlights with the white click animation state.  I could change the enabled state, except that that it would look disabled.  Is there a way to not allow the click state change without adding a view into the `UIBarButtonItem` and using a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can subclass UIBarButtonItem and make the corresponding UIView transparent with:

```
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a UILabel.  A label has text and by definition doesn't act like a button.  That way, you don't have to go out of your way to make a button act like a label :)